# Multiple has_many relationship Rails SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Coach and Sports connected by an Expertise level.  My Coach also has Courses.

I would like to get all of the Courses that have a Coach with a certain level of Expertise in a Sport given the Sports a User is interested in.

What is an efficient query to get the Courses available by Coaches of a certain Expertise in Sports that the User is interested in?

*Attempt*

```
Coach.includes(:expertises => :sport).
      where(["expertises.skill_level > ?", 0]).
      where(sports: {id: user.sports.map(&:id)})
```

*Attempt*

```
Course.joins(coach: {expertises: :sport})
      .where(
           expertises: {skill_level: 1}, 
           sports: {id: user.sports.map(&:id)}
       )
```

*Original Attempt*

```
coaches = []
qualified_coaches = []
courses = []
user_sports = User.sports
coach_quality_points_needed = user_sports.count
coach_quality_points

# get all the coaches who have an expertise in one of the user's sports
user_sports.each do |sport|
   coaches << Coach.joins(:expertises).where("expertises.sport_id = ?", sport.id)
end

# make list unique
coaches = coaches.uniq

# loop through the coaches
# add a point if they are skilled enough in each sport
coaches.each do |coach|
  coach_quality_points = 0
  user_sports.each do |user_sport|
    if coach.expertises.where(sport_id: user_sport.id).first.skill_level > 0
      coach_quality_points++
    end
  end

  # if the coach gets the necessary points then add to qualified list
  if coach_quality_points == coach_quality_points_needed
   qualified_coaches << coach 
end

# get all the courses of the qualified coaches
qualified_coaches.each do |coach|
  courses << Course.where(coach_id: coach.id)
end
```

These are my relationships.

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :sports 
end

create_table "users_sports", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "sport_id", null: false
    t.integer "user_id",  null: false
end
```

**Coach**

```
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :expertises 
  has_many :sports, through: :expertises
  has_many :courses
end
```

**Expertise**

```
class Expertise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coach
  belongs_to :sport
end

create_table "expertises", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "skill_level"
    t.integer  "coach_id"
    t.integer  "sport_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

**Sports**

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :expertises 
  has_many :coaches, through: :expertises
end
```

**Courses**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coach
end
```

Comment: What are the parameters that you are sending in for the Query?

Comment: @ruby_newbie I just added my current query to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your ActiveRecord query will look like this:

```
Course.joins(coach: {expertises: :sport}).where("expertises.skill_level >= ?", level).where(sports: {id: user.sports.map &:id})
```

where `level` is the expertise skill level you want and `user` is the user in question. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Why does it require me to call .uniq on the result?  I would like to be able to get expertise with a skill_level > 0

Comment: You must be getting duplicate rows returned because a course marches more than one expertise or coach. I'll update the query to search by skill level instead of expertise id

Comment: Just updated my answer - I'm just on my phone so I wasn't able to test it - let me know if it works

Comment: Hint: the last `where` can be expressed just as `.merge(user.sports)`. Or at least you could use `select` without a proc instead of `map` to have that part be a subquery.